# Is there a way to attach a Javascript object to a Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery

When building up a list of options in a select list using Javascript I'd like to attach a Javascript object to that option that I could easily retrieve in the change event.

So, while writing this question I wanted to provide some sample code and found a way to make this work; so I have a slight addition to the question. Is it bad to attach javascript object to DOM elements? Back in the day I remember there being issues with memory leaks in certain circumstances.

Here's a working example:
http://jsbin.com/afolo3/edit

```
var objs = [
  { id: 1, value: "One", type: "number" },
  { id: 2, value: "Two", type: "number" },
  { id: 3, value: "Three", type: "number" },
  { id: "A", value: "A", type: "char" },
  { id: "B", value: "B", type: "char" },
  { id: "C", value: "C", type: "char" },
  ];

var options = $.map(objs, function(item, idx) {
  var opt = $("<option/>").val(item.id).text(item.value);
  opt[0]["obj"] = item;
  return opt;
});

$.fn.append.apply($("#select"), options)
  .change(function() {
    $("#select option:selected")
      .each(function(){
    alert(this.obj.type);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Don't think that your case will created memory leaks - unless if you are creating the element using JS code and then inserting it to the DOM. If you have the select element html code in place and just populate the options using JS i don't think that you will be having memory leaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function instead.

Updated example: http://jsbin.com/afolo3/2

Comment: Thanks for providing the link and changing the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly attach objects to element instances the way you have; in fact, that's how jQuery does its `data` magic behind-the-scenes in the current version.

That said, since you're using jQuery *already*, I'd probably use the jQuery API for this ([`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)) instead, just in case it turns out that at some stage, a browser comes on the scene where a workaround is required — you'll get the benefit of the jQuery maintainers doing the workaround for you, rather than having to do it yourself.

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/afolo3/3) what it would look like using `data`. Basically to set the data:

```
opt.data("obj", item);
```

...and to retrieve and show its `type` property:

```
alert(opt.data("obj").type);
```

...where in each case, `opt` is a jQuery object for the `option` element in question.

One slight "gotcha" with jQuery's `data` function: If you retrieve a data object you've never set, you'll get `null` back (rather than `undefined`, which would be the usual JavaScript convention).

Comment: Great!, that's exactly what I was looking for.